# Does in svn branch is a simple copy?

Tags: svn, merge, copy, branch

For better understanding:
does in svn branch is a copy of some other branch(trunk)?
I mean that svn doesn't trak any relation between them?
So I can create copy name as branch myproject-x.y.z, commit it and that will be branch?
So I could use operations like merge?
Thanks.

Comment: When you say "So I can create copy name as branch myproject-x.y.z, commit it and that will be branch?" could you include a command line example of what you mean by "create copy name as branch myproject-x.y.z"?

Comment: thanks for question. I mean to copy only project files, not .svn files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes ,You have to make the copy of your project tree in the repository using the svn copy command. Your source code copy will be created.You can choose any name for the branch you wish.

Now you the copy, you can Checkout the code.

```
$ svn checkout http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/branches/my-calc-branch
A  my-calc-branch/Makefile
A  my-calc-branch/integer.c
A  my-calc-branch/button.c
Checked out revision 341.
$
```

Subversion is aware of the history of your branch and knows when it split away from the trunk. To perform a sync merge, first make sure your working copy of the branch is “clean”—that it has no local modifications reported by svn status. Then simply run:

```
$ pwd
/home/user/my-calc-branch
$ svn merge ^/calc/trunk
--- Merging r345 through r356 into '.':
U   button.c
U   integer.c
--- Recording mergeinfo for merge of r345 through r356 into '.':
U   .
$
```

Use svn status to check the code changes from main copy.

```
$ svn status
M      .
M  button.c
M  integer.c 
$
```

Refer my favorite http://svnbook.red-bean.com/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you `svn copy source_url/trunk source_url/myproject-x.y.z -m "Insert comment here"` you have created branch `myproject-x.y.z`.  There is no explicitly tracked connection between the two.  After making more commits on `myproject-x.y.z` you could merge it into `trunk`, but you could also choose to merge it into a hypothetical `branch_b`.

You do have to use the `svn copy` command though rather than dos `copy` or Unix/Linux/OSX `cp`.